# How to change the font of the letter "s" in math mode?

Tags: math-mode, fonts

I have a formula that has the letter "s". It is shown as *s*. I would like to change this font to an "s" like the one written by hand (only in this formula). See the picture for an illustration.

[image]

My code is this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[mathlf,footnotefigures,minionint,textlf]{MinionPro}
%\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}
%\usepackage[lite,subscriptcorrection,slantedGreek,nofontinfo]{mtpro2}

\begin{document}

My formula is \[f(s) = s^2+s+1.\]

But I would like the ``$s$'' to be like ...

\end{document}
```

PS. I used three dots in the code since I didn't include the graphics for "s".

Comment: Welcome! Is there a font which contains an 's' of the kind you want?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Unless the hand-drawn be is required: is it just the shape or the shape and the hand-drawnedness?

Comment: @cfr Sorry I deleted my comment as I thought it's better for the first comment to be a welcome. Maybe the OP can define a `\s` as loading the hand-drawn image with `\includegraphics`, and use that in the formula. :-) Hopefully it will become clearer what is wanted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try one of the [available script fonts](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/calligraphicalfonts.html). I don’t really know if this is really a nice solution.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage[mathlf,footnotefigures,minionint,textlf]{MinionPro}
%\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}
%\usepackage[lite,subscriptcorrection,slantedGreek,nofontinfo]{mtpro2}
\usepackage{calligra}
\newcommand{\s}{\mbox{\calligra{s}}}

\usepackage{wedn}
\newcommand{\salt}{\mbox{\wedn{s}}}

\begin{document}

My formula is \[f(\salt) = \s^2+\s+1.\]

But I would like the ``$s$'' to be like $\s$ or like $\salt$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I guess some fine tuning is needed if you use Calligra, like `\newcommand{\s}{\rotatebox{20}{\large\calligra{s}}}` ...